# OMNET++ 5 GUI nodes overlapped

Tags: omnet++

**OMNETPP 5, GUI nodes are overlapped with each other!**

I am new in OMNETPP environment and working with omnet++ 5.

While developing my first network, I created the tic-toc network and find okay.

But after some while, when I again run it, I found the nodes are overlapped with each other (see the attached pic) and its happen every times.

It is happening for most of my own projects, but not with the sample projects.

Does anyone have any clue please?

Check your doctrine configuration. Maybe XML mapping overrides annotations and that's why it's not working.

FH Overlapped Nodes:

[image: Overlapped Nodes]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. In omnet 5 all networks suddenly looked like yours. I changed back to 4.6 as a colleague didn't seem to have this problem and he's running 4.6. In 4.6 the tic/toc examples look and runs fine, however my custom network doesn't.

The screen I attached shows how the network looks in the editor vs how it looks in the simulation environment (in 4.6). [image: network_description_failure]

@edit: found the problem: Omnet decided to zoom out to 0.01x without telling me. Zooming in finally revealed, that everything was where it is supposed to be...